# Jboss EAR deployment

Tags: deployment, jboss, ear

I have a trouble deploying an ear in jboss under eclipse.
I got a lot of NoClassDefFoundError (for example of Spring framework) that it will be solved by adding spring libraries to classpath. However all these class are saved under APP-INF/lib path of the EAR, why this is not working?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about JBoss AS 5.1. Hopefully someone will come along that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep your ear in D:\jboss5.1.0-GA-3\server\default\deploy path
thats enough
pls try once
Regards 
Nalika Paul